# Core data in Android

Tags: android

i have an iphone application that use core data for searching ,and in similar application  in andoird am using sqlite ,so my performance is lower than iphone , is there anything similar to core data in Android ?.Also can i get any performance  advantage by using ORM  (am searching in table contain records 7000+)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For readers who are looking for a Core Data replacement in Android, I suggest an ORM tool like greenDAO. It allows you work with Java objects and uses SQLite as its storage back end.

Comment: ,it have any advantage over ORMLite ?

Answer (score 2):

If simply searching a static db, you can get away with using this very safely:

```
yourSqliteDb.execSQL("PRAGMA synchronous = OFF");
```

If it is a live/production database of constantly changing things I would recommend against this for corruption reasons.  But it increases speeds quite dramatically.